# Authenticating to remote servers using the Fingerprint API

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I've been following this link   https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html
for the server side verification. But I think this is applicable to private android mobile(only personal fingerprint) to server verification.

But my case is little bit different. I want to store fingerprints of other people on my device ( making my device public) so that all people who have their fingerprints on my device should individually process their own transaction with the server.

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: bunch of useless tags

Comment: That's not how the fingerprint API is meant to be used. You just get a callback telling you if the user's fingerprint matched _any_ of the fingerprints enrolled on the device, but you don't get to know _which_ of the enrolled fingerprints it matched. Also, many devices probably have a pretty low limit on the number of fingerprints you can enroll.

Comment: thank u so much for your support. i reallly appreciate that.